# data.table: Sum by all existing combinations in table

Tags: r, group-by, sum, data.table

I have a data.table `out` like this (in reality it is much larger):

```
out <-      code weights group
        1:    2   0.387      1
        2:    1   0.399      1
        3:    2   1.610      1
        4:    3   1.323      2
        5:    2   0.373      2                                            
        6:    1   0.212      2
        7:    3   0.316      3
        8:    2   0.569      3
        9:    1   0.120      3
       10:    1   0.354      3
```

It has 3 groups with different codes (column 1). In group #1, the code 3 does not appear, while in the other it appears.

Then, I want to sum the weights for every group and code combination . I achieve this with this command:

```
sum.dt <- out[,.(sum(weights)), by=list(code,group)][order(-V1)]
```

This works well but it does not have the combination Group 1 with Code 3 because it is not in the `out` table. I would like to have all possible combinations in `sum.dt`, and if the combination does not occur in the source table, it should sum up to 0, meaning the column `V1` should be 0 in this row.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: `setkey(out, code, group)`; `out[CJ(code,group,unique=TRUE)][, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(code,group)][order(group,-weights)]`

Comment: posted it as an answer

Comment: You might, also, find useful an array-like structure depending on what you're trying to do; `xtabs(weights ~ group + code, out)`

Answer (score 7):

Using `CJ` (cross join) you can add the missing combinations:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(out, code, group)
out[CJ(code, group, unique = TRUE)
    ][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(code, group)
      ][is.na(weights), weights := 0]
```

gives:

> ```
>    code group weights
> 1:    1     1   0.399
> 2:    1     2   0.212
> 3:    1     3   0.474
> 4:    2     1   1.997
> 5:    2     2   0.373
> 6:    2     3   0.569
> 7:    3     1   0.000
> 8:    3     2   1.323
> 9:    3     3   0.316
> ```

---

Or with `xtabs` as @alexis_laz showed in the comments:

```
xtabs(weights ~ group + code, out)
```

which gives:

> ```
>      code
> group     1     2     3
>     1 0.399 1.997 0.000
>     2 0.212 0.373 1.323
>     3 0.474 0.569 0.316
> ```

If you want to get this output in a long-form dataframe, you can wrap the `xtabs` code in the `melt` function of the *reshape2* (or *data.table*) package:

```
library(reshape2)
res <- melt(xtabs(weights ~ group + code, out))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > class(res)
> [1] "data.frame"
> > res
>   group code value
> 1     1    1 0.399
> 2     2    1 0.212
> 3     3    1 0.474
> 4     1    2 1.997
> 5     2    2 0.373
> 6     3    2 0.569
> 7     1    3 0.000
> 8     2    3 1.323
> 9     3    3 0.316
> ```

---

You could also do this with a combination of *dplyr* and *tidyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out %>%
  complete(code, group, fill = list(weights=0)) %>%
  group_by(code, group) %>% 
  summarise(sum(weights))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and `CJ` did not work for some reason. A relatively simple solution I ended up using is first calling `dcast` and then `melt` (similar to the `xtable` solution above)- this also conveniently lets you specify the fill value for the missing combinations.

```
sum.dt <- dcast(out, code ~ group, value.var = 'weights', 
                fun.aggregate = sum, fill = 0)
sum.dt <- melt(sum.dt, id.vars = 'code', variable.name = 'group')
```

This gives

```
> sum.dt
   code group value
1:    1     1 0.399
2:    2     1 1.997
3:    3     1 0.000
4:    1     2 0.212
5:    2     2 0.373
6:    3     2 1.322
7:    1     3 0.474
8:    2     3 0.569
9:    3     3 0.316
```